# What does the word "company" mean in the context of collocation analysis in corpus linguistics?

Tags: corpora, collocations, corpus-linguistics

I am currently reading Brezina (2018) on Statistics in Corpus Linguistics. I have a hard time trying to decipher what the author means of "**company**" in this sentence:

> Dice and log Dice, and MI2 favour collocates which occur exclusively in each other’s **company** but do not have to be rare.

I understand that **collocates** are words that co-occur with a **node** in a specifically defined **span**, where **node** here refers to the word that we want to analyze and **span** refers to the words that co-occur side-by-sde of a **node**.

For example, the **node** "love" has these following **collocations** in a **span** of 1L and 1R collocation window:

| 1L | node | 1R |
| --- | --- | --- |
| my | love | is |
| to | love | you |
| my | love |  |
| our | love |  |

My current understanding of "**company**" in this context is the node and collocation pairs in a given corpus, but I might be wrong. Therefore your explanation is very valuable. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn’t seem like a special or jargonistic use to me; it’s just how the word _company_ works in English. It’s no different to talking about people who enjoy each other’s company (enjoy being around each other); here it just means words that only appear around (≈ next to) each other.

Comment: Hi @JanusBahsJacquet, so just like my current understanding then. Thanks!

Comment: company here means environment. collocate just means to occur with. Words occur in an environment. You would not expect "drain pipe" and "baby doll" to collocate.

Answer (score 1):

The word *company* is sometimes used in collocation analysis due to a quote by [J.R. Firth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Rupert_Firth) (1957): "You shall know a word by the company it keeps".

It basically just refers to the context, ie the surrounding words. There is -- to my knowledge -- no specific span given by Firth, ie the extend of the context is not limited to any particular size.